# How to connect dlink dwm156 on ubuntu 12.04lts?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb

Hi my system config are:

```
Dell Inspiron N4010
Intel i3 4gb RAM
500GB HDD
dual boot windows 7 ultimate 64 bit and ubuntu 12.04lts 32 bit
Dlink DWM-156 H/W ver: A7     firmware:A7.0.1IN
```

`lsusb` gives following after I insert datacard

```
lsusb                   
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:641d Microdia 1.3 MPixel Integrated Webcam
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2001:a706 D-Link Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
```

But datacard not get detected in network connection

Please help me. I am newbie in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Windows then boot in Windows and then conect and use your data card then restart and boot into ubuntu , now it will detect your card if it doesnt then go to the next step.

If you have access to GSM mobile(or GSM Modem) with cheap GPRS plan, then connect your mobile to Ubuntu through Network Manager and install WVDIAL. I have never experienced any difficulty with GSM Modem when connecting to Internet through Network Manager.Press Ctrl+Alt+t for terminal and write the following commands:

For installing Wvdial;

```
sudo apt-get install wvdial
```

For Opening wvdial config:

```
gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

and write your datacard info like this for relience:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = USB Modem
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0(cud be anything based on where u plugin ur usb dongle)
Username = 7********* 
Password = 7*********
CBaud = 46080
```

Delete all the comments in the brackets . The fields you should edit are Modem , Username and password the only ones with comment . Save and exist .restart your PC and open terminal and write

`sudo wvdial`

for connecting to internet.